# c++ boost::bind vs clojure partial function

Tags: c++, clojure, functional-programming

the c++ boost bind library and clojure's partial function are very similar. For example:

```
int x = 8;
bind(std::less<int>(), _1, 9)(x);   // x < 9
```

This is similar to clojure's partial function:

```
((partial > 9) 8)
```

The difference is that `partial` only allows the first n parameters to be bound, whereas `boost::bind` allows placeholders indicating which parameters are bound and which are unbound. So `boost::bind` is actually much more general and useful:

```
bind(f, _2, _1)(x, y);                 // f(y, x)

bind(g, _1, 9, _1)(x);                 // g(x, 9, x)
```

I'm wondering if there is something similar to `boost::bind` in clojure (or clojure-contrib)? And why partial was not written to be more general (and useful) as `boost::bind` is?

Comment: by that reasoning, why include partial in the language at all? It's just a special case of a lambda. I personally think partial is more clear.

Comment: But C++03 doesn't have lambda.

Comment: if you want place holders you can just wrap it in an anonymous lambda: (def partial-plus #(+ 9 %1 %2 %3))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a fairly frequently asked question of Clojure, more often couched in terms of the threading macros -> and ->> as to why they also don't allow arbitrary placeholders.

The reason given for those also applies here in my opinion: idiomatic Clojure functions generally breakdown into ones that lend themselves to having either their first or their last arguments supplied separately, not a mixture.

In other words, developers generally try to code functions so that they are amenable to ->, ->> and/or partial.

Given the reader macro for anonymous functions, it's fairly easy to create the placeholder versions when they're needed, for less idiomatic situations:

```
#(f %2 %1) ;; bind(f, _2, _1)
#(g % 9 %) ;; bind(g, _1, 9, _1)
```

Comment: This is interesting because I almost mentioned the threading macros. What you say might be true but the rule breaks down as soon as you start calling java methods which invariably don't follow this rule. Then I'm forced to write less concise code than I'd like, because the threading macro is not as general as it could be. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: Or more typically what happens is, I want to thread an arg thru 5 methods and 4 need to be threaded as the first arg, and the fifth needs the value threaded as the last arg.

Comment: This may not be idiomatic, but I wrote this macro a while ago and have found it useful. It is similar to -> or ->>, but threads based on % markers. E.g. (%-> 300 (/ % 10) (/ 60 %)) would return 2.
(defmacro %->
  ([x] x)
  ([x form] (if (seq? form)
              (with-meta (postwalk-replace {'% x} form) (meta form))
              (list form x)))
  ([x form & more] `(%-> (%-> ~x ~form) ~@more)))

Answer (score 0):

Like Sean said, `partial` solves a more specific problem and in general, lambdas are the idiomatic solution. That said, if you're desperate, you can always roll your own `bind`:

```
(defmacro bind
  [bound-function & args]
  (let [; helper function to parse actual argument symbols
        get-symbols (fn [s] (map second s)),
        ; help function to get the placeholder arguments
        get-placeholders (fn [s] (filter first s))
        ; collection of arguments and whether they're placeholders
        bound-args (map (fn [arg]
                        (if (= arg '_)
                          ; for placeholders, generate a new symbol
                          [true (gensym)]
                          ; otherwise, use the provided argument as-is
                          [false arg]))
                      args)]
    `(fn [~@(get-symbols (get-placeholders bound-args))]
       (~bound-function ~@(get-symbols bound-args)))))
```

Its use is as follows:

```
((bind > 9 _) 8) ; true
((bind > _ _) 9 8 ) ; true
```

Comment: The placeholders need to be numbered or the args can't be reordered/ignored etc. but I get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

There's the [Swiss Arrows](https://github.com/rplevy/swiss-arrows) library that allows for various other parameter threading / binding scenario's. However, there's so many options in there that optimizing your function's parameters to best use the -> and ->> macro's the preferred solution, and if that's not possible, use anonymous functions as the simplest general solution.